# compiler error help (E2209 Unable to open include file)

Tags: c++, c++builder

I am using Borland C++ Builder 6. I have installed LMD Tool version 7, and ABC for Delphi 6 companion version (runtime pakage only).

When I compiled a software unit, I received the following error messages:

```
[C++ Error] iss_hmi_gui_cached.h(58): E2209 Unable to open include file 'abcbtn.hpp'
Full parser context
C++ Error] iss_hmi_gui_cached.h(59): E2209 Unable to open include file 'abcctl32.hpp'
Full parser context
[C++ Error] iss_hmi_gui_cached.h(61): E2209 Unable to open include file 'abcexctl.hpp'
```

and

```
[C++ Error] Lmdcontrol.hpp(24): E2209 Unable to open include file 'Uxtheme.hpp'
[C++ Error] Lmdcustomspeedbutton.hpp(22): E2209 Unable to open include file 'Uxtheme.hpp'
```

I have searched my PC, and I could not find Uxtheme.hpp anywhere.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

David.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UxTheme.h is part of the Windows SDK. The SDK comes with the newer versions of visual studio, but you can download it from [microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=F26B1AA4-741A-433A-9BE5-FA919850BDBF&displaylang=en). You will also have to tell the compiler where to find the SDK header and library files.

Answer (score 2):

Concerning the ABC errors, did you build with the

`Project|Options|Packages - Build with Runtime Packages`

checkbox checked?

And does your package names list include the appropriate runtime package?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like some of your source files are missing.